# Delete parameter from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How do you delete a parameter from a stored procedure?

I have this:

[image: imageOfDB]

And I want to get rid of those parameters, I didn't mean to query it with them like that, I was trying to modify my stored procedure and make them into columns not parameters.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You just edit the text of the stored procedure with SSMS, and edit out the parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry this is my first time every working with stored procedures and I'm working with one that was already made.

Comment: What tool are you using to create, edit and maintain your sql server objects?

Comment: sql server management studio

Comment: unless you mean the other end with visual studio?

Comment: Be forewarned though: you probably cannot just remove those parameters because it is probably using them in the SQL  statements in the stored procedure.

Comment: If there is any danger that this SP is already in use with the specified parameters then make the parameters optional rather than removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's not being used by anyone anywhere else. Open it in sql server management studio delete the parameters and where it's being used in the stored procedure. Test, test, test.